# onkeyup textbox, get value from span javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel

How can I get value from span using dynamic id and show in a text input?

I have this span id

```html
<span id="unitCost{{$data->product_id}}">700</span>
```

```
    **Onkeyup I want to get the span data.**
   
<input type="number" class="form-control total_cost " id="productId{{$data->product_id}}" onkeyup="calculate({{$data->product_id}})" min="0">
```

**Javascript I tried**

```
   calculate = function(id)
{
 var qty = document.getElementById('unitCost'+id).value;
    alert (qty);
}
```

Comment: `Javascript I tried` and what happened?

Comment: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')

Comment: to debug this situation, I would add some console.log's to the calculate function to see what is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `innerText` instead of `value`

```
calculate = function(id)
{
 var qty = document.getElementById('unitCost'+id).innerText;
    alert (qty);
}
```

Comment: Also please use on change. keyup wont work for clicking the up arrows of the number input.

Comment: if `document.getElementById('unitCost'+id)` is null (read comment by OP) then this isn't going to work either